# What story was Burton Richter referring to when he spoke of physics experiments getting too expensive to be funded?

Tags: story-identification

Nobel Prize (Physics 1976) winner Burton Richter (March 22, 1931 – July 18, 2018) [wrote](http://inspirehep.net/record/1314991/files/slac-pub-16069.pdf) in 2014;

> When I was much younger I was a fan of science fiction books. I have never
>   forgotten the start of one, **though I don’t remember the name of the book or its author. It began by saying that high-energy physics’ and optical astronomy’s instruments had gotten so expensive that the fields were no longer funded.**

**To what book or story was Richter referring?**

Comment: I assume you mean to be asking the question "What story was Richter remembering?" If so, better fix your question to make that clear before the off-topic police close it!

Comment: @MarkOlson - Or you could fix it yourself with [edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/205964/edit)?

Comment: Bruce Sterling's "The Dead Collider" seems to recent, at 1994, but was published in *The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction* (http://vadeker.net/articles/sterling/collider.txt)

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - He wrote the article in 2014 so a gap of 20 years might be sufficient for the author to mis-remember how long ago it was that he read a book) or he might just have meant "*when I was 20 years younger"*

Comment: I voted to close as there's no way to verify an answer as correct. So any answer will be opinion based.

Comment: @Moriarty Well, a story that begins as stated which was written before, say, 2000, would be a pretty strong likelihood. I've read a *lot* of SF and I don't recall anything that starts with this, so it's not likely to be a common trope.  (Besides, I probably read the same physics blog that the OP read and wondered what the story was also -- I just didn't think of posting the question here.)

Answer (score 5):

This may be stretching things a bit, but Bruce Sterling wrote "[The Dead Collider](http://vadeker.net/articles/sterling/collider.txt)" for *The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction* in July of 1994, which was 25 years ago.

> SCIENCE magazine, in its editorial post-mortem "The Lessons of the
>    Super Collider," had its own morals to draw.  Lesson One:  "High energy
>    physics has become too expensive to be defined by national boundaries."
>    Lesson Two:  "Just because particle physics asks questions about the
>    fundamental structure of matter does not give it any greater claim on
>    taxpayer dollars than solid-state physics or molecular biology.
>    Proponents of any project must justify the costs in relation to the
>    scientific and social return."
>
> That may indeed be the New Reality for American science funding
>    today, but it was never the justification of the Machine in the Desert.  The
>    Machine in the Desert was an absolute vision, about the absolute need to
>    know.

However, there's no mention of astronomy in either that paper or the referenced *Science* article, "[The Lessons of the Super Collider](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/262/5141/1799)", and neither is actually science fiction.